# Dynamic swap file

Tags: ubuntu, swap

Is there a way of creating a dynamic swap file on elementary OS? I know Ubuntu has a tool to do so with a fixed file size but it seems a little buggy. Also I have found a tool for Ubuntu which creates dynamically sized swap but seems to be outdated.

Is this just a kernel limitation or can it be done?

The reason for this is that I have an old laptop with a Intel Corei3 Processor, and 4GB of RAM. While running Ubuntu on it, as soon as I have multiple tabs open it starts freezing. So i tried repartitioning the swap partition yet at a certain stage in open applications it starts freezing again which makes it necessary to resize the swap partition again and that is just annoying a ridiculous. Even if I use a large swap partition I'm afraid it's still not stable.

So I have wiped out Ubuntu and installed Windows 10 and it runs like a breeze. Yet I really want linux on the laptop so I'm looking for alternative distributions that might have the capability of dynamic allocated swap file.

The only Unix like OS that I see does this very well is Mac OS. So why has this not been ported to Linux?